# Can we configure Talend for data integration to use SSL

Tags: talend

Can we configure Talend for data integration to use SSL.
I have gone through some the links and talend community and learnt that it could be done for Talend ESB .Wanted to know how we do the same for Talend for data integration

Comment: How do you want to use SSL? Via an REST API? This works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1** option to your JVM.

If you are facing some problems with component (like tRest) and you are using java <= 7 know that the TLSv1 is used by default to perform TLS handshake. This can block connection with servers using greater version of TLS.

Think that this issue is resolved with java 8.